# Can the ViewBag name be the same as the Model property name in a DropDownList?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper, html.dropdownlistfor

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC-4 web application. I'm defining the following inside my action method to build a `SelectList`:

```
ViewBag.CustomerID = new SelectList(db.CustomerSyncs, "CustomerID", "Name");
```

Then I am rendering my `DropDownListFor` as follow inside my `View`:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerID, (SelectList)ViewBag.CustomerID, "please select")
```

As shown I am naming the `ViewBag` property to be equal to the `Model` property name which is `CustomerID`. From my own testing, defining the same name didn't cause any problem or conflict but should I avoid this ?

Comment: Do not do this - it does cause problems (for example you cannot get any client side validation)

Comment: @StephenMuecke clien validation on what? ViewBag doesn't have any validation

Comment: @teovankot, on the model property `CustomerID` - with OP's usage, there will be no `data-val-*` attributes generated and of the user selects the first "please select" option, no validation error will be displayed (when it should be - assuming `CustomerID` is typeof `int`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke why i will not get any client side validation .... now i have the customerID as int and it is required. and by default i got a client side validation , that when a user try to submit a form he will get an error that the CustomerID is required... so not sure what do you mean by i cannot get any client side validation ...

Comment: Another issue is that if the value of `CustomerID` is set in the controller (i.e. editing and existing entity), it will not selected correctly in the dropdownlist.

Comment: @StephenMuecke why will it not get selected correctly ,, can you advice more?is this realted to using the same name for the viewbag and the model property ?

Comment: @StephenMuecke retruning back to the client validation .. now the value for the "please select" will be null,, so the client side validation will still work .. here is the markup   <select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field CustomerID must be a number." data-val-required="The CustomerID field is required." id="CustomerID" name="CustomerID"><option value="">please select</option>
<option value="1">CustomerA</option>

Comment: @johnG, Refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OxriS9). Note that the value of `ClientID` is set to 2 which matches the 2nd option, yet it is **not** selected in the view

Comment: @johnG, Note the comment about the validation not working only applies to using `@Html.DropDownList("CustomerID", (SelectList)ViewBag.CustomerID, ....)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes i know using DropDownList will not force client side validation.. that why i am using DropdownListfor() .. ..

Comment: @StephenMuecke so option 2 is not select since the name for the viewbag and the name for the model property is the same ?

Comment: @johnG, It will force validation using `DropDownList` if the names are different :) There are 2 ery good reason why you should never use the same nae for the model property and the view bag property.

Comment: @StephenMuecke ok, you right. My appologies

Comment: If you want get `CustomerID` from dropdown, better use: `@Html.DropDownList("CustomerID", null, "please select")`

Comment: @SeM, Absolutely not. You will not get client side validation.

Comment: @StephenMuecke so if i use the following "ViewBag.Customers = new SelectList(db.CustomerSyncs, "CustomerID", "Name")" .. then i use the following  "@Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.CustomerID,(SelectList)ViewBag.Customers, "please select")" .. where i rename my viewbag to be customers .. will it work correctly?

Comment: @StephenMuecke but you can write your own client side validation in JS, just checking for first parameter (by its index), am I wrong?

Comment: @johnG, Yes that will work correctly. I will add an answer a bit later explaining the issues and how the methods work internally.

Comment: @StephenMuecke you **will get validation** [check Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3fPX6q). But still there is this issue with default selected value

Comment: @teovankot, As I noted above, the validation issue is when you use the `DropDownList()` method. I'm adding an answer and will update the fiddle showing all use cases

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should not use the same name for the model property and the `ViewBag` property (and ideally you should not be using `ViewBag` at all, but rather a view model with a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` property).

When using `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CustomerId, ....)` the first `"Please Select"` option will always be selected even if the value of the model property has been set and matches one of the options. The reason is that the method first generates a new `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` based on the one you have supplied in order to set the value of the `Selected` property. In order to set the `Selected` property, it reads the value of `CustomerID` from `ViewData`, and the first one it finds is `"IEnumerable<SelectListItem>"` (not the value of the model property) and cannot match that string with any of your options, so the first option is selected (because something has to be).

When using `@Html.DropDownList("CustomerId", ....)`, no `data-val-*` attributes will be generated and you will not get any client side validation

Refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OxriS9) showing a comparison of possible use cases. Only by using different names for the model property and the `ViewBag` property will it all work correctly.

Comment: Error in fiddle , when i click on submit button . It says "The ViewData item that has the key 'CustomerA' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'. "

Comment: @Saurabh, That's because I did not repopulate the `SelectLists` in the POST method before returning the view (as per the GET method) - but that is not the point of the fiddle - its to show that you cannot get correct 2-way binding and/or validation if the same name is used for property your binding to and the `SelectList` (and if you want more details on that error - refer [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366305/the-viewdata-item-that-has-the-key-xxx-is-of-type-system-int32-but-must-be-o)

Answer (score 1):

There is not harm to use it. You will not get any error. but best practice is to bind model property.

Comment: @US3-57384 can you adivce more ?

Comment: See what i use in my code. which solve your issue and works fine. (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.RT