# MVC 6 , Get selected item from DropdownList(For)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model, controller, html.dropdownlistfor

This is editted !

**(I tryed the provided answer as well with the ViewData approach and this hasn't solved my answer)** since i can not post more than 2 links and i didn't kept all tryed suggestions this is the reason why this post does not contain all tryed methods in code.

Hello and thank you for reading this ,

I have spend over 4 hours with my teacher with this and we tryed all suggestions google gave us (over 10 different solutions) but none of them fixed it...

So what i want is to populate a dropdown with a list of objects (HotelChains).
The error im getting is:

> The ViewData item that has the key 'SelectedHotelChain' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'.

[This is my viewModel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fixkY.png)

[This is my Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKAdr.png)

(cant post more than 2 links)
My layout is like this :

```
Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedHotelChain, Model.HotelChains, "(boo)")
```

also tryed

```
@Html.DropDownList("HotelChains", Model.HotelChains, "(none)")
```

and with viewData also like this
 (with off course the appropiate notations in the model)

```
@Html.DropDownList("Options", ViewData["Options"] as SelectList, "--Select Item--")
```

We really tryed a lot of things also with ViewData[] and many others , this is for my dissertation (in 2 weeks) so i hope wome one can help me as i gonna have to switch to ASP if it doesn't get answered.

Kind Regards !

Comment: The error means only one thing as the dupe clearly explains. The value of `Model.HotelChains` is `null` (probably because you return the view in the post method and have not reassigned it).

Comment: And you 2nd and 3rd attempts will not work correctly - you cannot use the same name for the model you binding to and the `ViewData`/`ViewBag` property as explained in [this answer[(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37161202/will-there-be-any-conflict-if-i-specify-the-viewbag-name-to-be-equal-to-the-mode/37162557#37162557)

Comment: And do not provide links to code - the code must be included in your question.

Comment: So this is hard to say , but we where trying everything in the wrong controller ... Our first solution was actually working ...Sry for the disturbance and thank you for your time !