# Validate dropdownlist in mvc using (Html.ValidationMessage)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I know the dropdown list data is coming
from the viewBag not model , thats why model doesnt validate the    particular dropdown 
list while it validates other fields which are linked to model,
Just want to know, how can i validate the above dropdownlist

***This doesnt works on (ModelState.IsValid)***

**Controller**

```
var td = tabladatos.GetAll();
var estadossol = (from item in td
                  where item.Relacion == "EstadoSolicitud" && !(item.Valor == 1 || item.Valor == 3 || item.Valor == 4 || item.Valor == 5)
                  orderby item.Orden ascending
                  select item).ToList();

ViewBag.EstadoSolicitud = new SelectList(estadossol, "Valor", "Descripcion", "2");
```

**View**

```
@Html.DropDownList("EstadoSolicitud", null, "", new { @class = "select2_single form-control" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EstadoSolicitud)
```

Comment: Check [Here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1900637.aspx?jQuery+Validate+Unobtrusive+no+validation+message+for+dropdown). I guess this is what you need.

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will there be any conflict if i specify the viewBag name to be equal to the model property name inside @Html.DropDownListFor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37161202/will-there-be-any-conflict-if-i-specify-the-viewbag-name-to-be-equal-to-the-mode)

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the selected value of the dropdown to a value in your model, and then display a message for that.

#### Model

```
[Required]
public int? SeleccionadoValor { get; set; }
```

#### Razor

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SeleccionadoValor, ViewBag.EstadoSolicitud)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SeleccionadoValor)
```