# DropdownListFor initial value does not selected in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In Controller Method, my code is below

```
ViewBag.CurrencyNameId = db.CurrencyNames;
```

In View code in Edit.cshtml is

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CurrencyNameId, new SelectList(ViewBag.CurrencyNameId, "Id", "Name",Model.CurrencyNameId), "Select", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

It does not set initial value.

Comment: First, your cannot use the same name for the property your binding to and the `SelectList` (refer [Will there be any conflict if i specify the viewBag name to be equal to the model property name inside @Html.DropDownListFor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37161202/will-there-be-any-conflict-if-i-specify-the-viewbag-name-to-be-equal-to-the-mode/37162557#37162557). Second, there is no point at all in the 4th parameter of the `SelectList` constructor - its ignored when binding to a model property.

Comment: And assuming your `CurrencyNameId` is typeof `int` - then its that value which determines what is selected. Just set its value in the GET method to the value of one of the option values, and it will be selected (after making the changes noted above) - `@@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CurrencyNameId, new SelectList(ViewBag.CurrencyList, "Id", "Name), .... )`

Comment: Thanks, @Stephen for your answer.It works for me.