# DropDownList default during Edit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

During Edit I am getting the values form table ScannerTypes as follows into ViewBag as follows

```
ViewBag.ScannerTypeID = new SelectList(db.ScannerTypes, "ScannerTypeID", "Name", db.ScannerTypes);
```

For few rows the value of `ScannerTypeID` could be `null`. If the `ScannerTypeID` is `null`, I want to show default message as "Select Scanner Type" else I want to show the selected Name. Here is my Razor code

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ScannerTypeID, "Scanner Type", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("ScannerTypeID", null, "Select Scanner Type", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ScannerTypeID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately for all edit I am getting messages as  "Select Scanner Type".

Comment: You need to set the value of property `ScannerTypeID` in the GET method before you pass the model to the view. And delete the `db.ScannerTypes` property from the `SelectList` constructor (the `Selected` property is ignored when binding to a property).

Comment: And you cannot have the same name for the property and the `SelectList` (refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37161202/will-there-be-any-conflict-if-i-specify-the-viewbag-name-to-be-equal-to-the-mode/37162557#37162557)) - use `ViewBag.ScannerList = ....` and `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ScannerTypeID", (SelectList)ViewBag.ScannerList, .... )`

Comment: But you have said _For few rows_ - are you doing something in a loop? (in which case you need other changes as well)