# Mvc, Selectlist selected object value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this selectlist:

controller:

```
 ViewBag.SagId = new SelectList(db.Sags, "Id", "Emne", 7);
```

list and everything works as suposed to, but the selected value is not == 7,

View:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SagId,(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) ViewBag.SagId,
new
{

    @class = "selectpickers",
    data_show_subtext = "true",
    data_live_search = "true"

})
```

its probably some stupid thing i have missed?

Comment: Model binding works by binding to the value of your property. Set the value of `SagId` to `7` in the GET method before you pass the model to the view and it will be selected. The 4th parameter of the `SelectList` constructor is ignored when you bind to a property

Comment: i don't want it to always be 7, just a test wanted it to be an int that can change depending on what site they visit.

Comment: It does not matter what the actual value is. You need to set the value of property `SagId` and if that matches one of the option values it will be selected (otherwise the first option will be selected because something has to be) - that is how model binding works.

Comment: hmm there is a value = 7, on SagsId. first think i was looking for aswell.

Comment: so you're saying, i should set it in my get? how would you do that ?

Comment: `var model = new YourModel(){ SagId = 7 }; return View(model);`

Comment: yes, oka thanks for your help. Got it working now. if u want you can make an answer i will accept it. :) @StephenMuecke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model binding works by binding to the value of your model property. You need to set the value of property `SagId` in the controller before you pass the model to the view.

Your code in your controller method should be something like

```
var model = new YourModel()
{
    SagId = 7
};
ViewBag.SagId = new SelectList(db.Sags, "Id", "Emne");
return View(model);
```

Note that there is not point setting the 4th parameter in the `SelectList` constructor. It's ignored when binding to a model property because internally the `DropDownListFor()` method builds its own `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` and sets the `Selected` property based on the value of the property your binding to.

Note also that you should not use the same names for the property your binding to (refer [Can the ViewBag name be the same as the Model property name in a DropDownList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37161202/will-there-be-any-conflict-if-i-specify-the-viewbag-name-to-be-equal-to-the-mode/37162557#37162557)), and I strongly recommend that you use a view model, especially when editing, and that view model will contain a property `public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SagList { get; set; }` and in the view it will be `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SagId, Model.SagList, new { ... })`