# How to get dropdown text value and text name from viewBag in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Hello friends this really basic question in mvc, but iam lot of search i couldn't find it.

**Control:**

```
if (objResponse.ErrorNo == 0)
 {
     lstReason.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Select" });
     foreach (XElement xEle in resXml.Descendants("R"))
             {
               lstReason.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = xEle.Element("C1").Value, Text = xEle.Element("C2").Value });
              }
               ViewBag.ReasonCode = lstReason;

                }
   }
```

**View:**

`@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ReasonCode, new SelectList(ViewBag.ReasonCode, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "form-control autofocus", @id = "ddlReason"` })

I got it only `m => m.ReasonCode` but how can get m.reason from ViewBag.ReasonCode text value.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can the ViewBag name be the same as the Model property name in a DropDownList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37161202/can-the-viewbag-name-be-the-same-as-the-model-property-name-in-a-dropdownlist)

Comment: As a side note, creating an identical `IEnumerable<SelectLisItem>` from the original one using `new SelectList(..)` in the view is pointless extra overhead.

Comment: And the normal way to add the option label is using [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor``2(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper{``0},System.Linq.Expressions.Expression{System.Func{``0,``1}},System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable{System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem},System.String,System.Object) which add a `null` value for validation

Answer (score 1):

Your `ViewBag` member cannot be named the same as your model property. The "selected" value is determined from `ModelState`, which is composed of values from `Request`, `ViewData`/`ViewBag` and finally `Model`. As a result, you're essentially saying the that "selected" value should be the entire list of `SelectListItem`s, which obviously does not match an item in that list. Change your `ViewBag` member to something like `ViewBag.ReasonCodeOptions`, and you'll be good.

Comment: ok am change my viewbag name but how can catch value of drop-down text name value @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ReasonCode)
                          @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ReasonText)