# Remote Validation DropDownList MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, data-annotations

I want to Check whether the master type already exists or not using remote validation.

In my case the remote validation method is not firing.Can anyone help me?

### Model

```
  [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
  [StringLength(200)]
  [Display(Name = "MasterType")]
  [Remote("IsNameAvailable", "MasterSetUps", ErrorMessage = "Master type already exists ")]
  public string MasterType { get; set; }
```

### Validation Method

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public JsonResult IsNameAvailable(string MasterType)
    {
        bool result = true;
        if (s_mode == "ADD")
        {
            return Json(!db.MasterSetUps.Any(a => a.MasterType == MasterType), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else if (s_mode == "EDIT" & MasterType != s_Master_Type_name)
        {
            return Json(!db.MasterSetUps.Any(a => a.MasterType == MasterType), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

### View

```
<div class="form-group">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MasterType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-sm-2" })
   <div class="col-sm-10">
     @Html.DropDownList("MasterType", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-controls" })
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MasterType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
   </div>
</div>
```

### GetMethod

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  s_mode = "ADD";
  ViewBag.MasterType = new SelectList(db.Masters, "MasterType", "MasterType");
  return View();
}
```

Comment: Your property is `string` so your view code for the `DropDownList` makes no sense (and certainly will not generate any `data-val` attributes necessary for validation). Show the code for your GET method

Comment: Why not using `DropDownListFor` while `ValidationMessageFor` exists: `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MasterType, ViewBag.MasterType as SelectList, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-2" })`?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Thanks for your sugession..Its working :) Thank You.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank you for your effort.Got an alternative method :)

Comment: That will not work correctly!

Comment: Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37161202/can-the-viewbag-name-be-the-same-as-the-model-property-name-in-a-dropdownlist/37162557#37162557) to understand why

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `DropDownList(...)` means that your not generating the necessary `data-val-*` attributes for validation. The method is using your `ViewBag` property for binding (not your model property) and their are no validation attributes associated with `ViewBag`.

Change the code in the GET method to

```
ViewBag.MasterTypeList = new SelectList (.....
```

and the view code to

```
@Html.DropDownListFor (m => m.MasterType, (SelectList)ViewBag.MasterTypeList, new { ... })
```

Note that the name of the property your binding to cannot be the same as the `SelectList`.

Comment: hi there, how to bind `selectedValue` from controller?

Comment: @ColourDalnet, If the vale of the property you are binding to (`MasterType` in this case) matches one of the option values (in `MasterTypeList`), then the correct option will be selected.

Comment: I thought so, but... when I bound like OP question, it is bound perfectly but Validation not working properly. Doing in your way making validation working perfectly but, binding the data not working. I will iterate the code once again and ask new question if not working. Thank you.