# Generate dropdown list in Register for mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

My register page requires a dropdownlist that is populated with names from the Customer table. I have included the Customer foreign key in my AspNetUsers table in order to then reference the Customernames, I've added this field in the registerViewModel and IdentityModel. However not quite sure how to access CustomerNames using the CustomerId in the register form as a dropdownlist. Below is what I've tried:

AccountController:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, CustomerID=model.CustomerID};
        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

            ViewBag.CustomerID = new SelectList(db.Customers, "CustomerID", "CustomerCompanyName");
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        AddErrors(result);
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

View:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    @Html.Label("Customer ID")
</div>
<div class="col-md-9">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CustomerID, new SelectList(ViewBag.CustomerID, "CustomerID", "CustomerName"))
</div>
```

Comment: `ViewBag.CustomerID` is already a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, so its `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CustomerID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>ViewBag.CustomerID)`, but that will not work correctly anyway - refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37161202/will-there-be-any-conflict-if-i-specify-the-viewbag-name-to-be-equal-to-the-mode/37162557#37162557). ALWAYS use a view model, and in your case it will include `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)CustomerList` and the view will be `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CustomerID, Model.CustomerList`

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke, tell me if I am understanding correctly, should I create a class under Models that will contain all the names that I require in the dropdown?

Comment: No, In your `RegisterViewModel`, add a property `public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CustomerList { get; set; }` . Refer both [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366305/the-viewdata-item-that-has-the-key-xxx-is-of-type-system-int32-but-must-be-o) for a typical example (and note you only set it in the POST method if `ModelState` is not valid - there is no point setting it if your redirecting as in your code)

Comment: Okay, so in your first comment, where do i now add this IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)CustomerList

Comment: As per my last comment (the `)` is a typo) - and look at the link I gave you previously

Answer (score 0):

you're in the wrong action method, put your viewbag in this Method instead:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
ViewBag.CustomerID = new SelectList(db.Customers, "CustomerID", "CustomerCompanyName");
            return View();
        }
```

Dropdown in view:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerID,
     (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)@ViewBag.CustomerID , htmlAttributes: new
      {
          @class = "Form-control",

      })
```

Comment: No, you're inside the Httppost. If you haven't edited the order, it should be right above.

Comment: Oh sorry. but yes I've included the ViewBag in the Register Get method also, but it breaks in the view at the "DropDownListFor..." line

Comment: Look my Edit, that's the way i useally do it.

Comment: Using `ViewBag` when OP already has a view model is awful - and this will not bind correctly anyway

Comment: Stephen Muecke is right you should use your View model

Answer (score 0):

@Unicorn_Girl,You should try this,

```
  ViewBag.CustomerID = new SelectList(db.Customers.Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(x, x)), "CustomerID", "CustomerCompanyName");

   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CustomerID, new SelectList(ViewBag.CustomerID, "Text", "Value"), "Select CustomerID", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

I hope this is useful

Comment: Create a 2nd identical `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` from the 1st one is pointless extra overhead