# Why does a ViewBag Object Name need to be the same name as the Drop Down it is being bound to?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, viewbag

I've got a Razor cshtml setup where I am sending a SelectList through the ViewBag.  My issue is the naming of the ViewBag object, I would like to send it like this (see below) but doesn't seem to be working for me.

Controller:

```
ViewBag.EmailAddresses = new[]
    {
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Select an Email Address", Value = "" }
    }
    .Concat(
        new SelectList( db.EmailAddresses, "Oid", "Name", null )
    );
```

Razor view:

```
@Html.DropDownList(
    "FromRecipientID", 
    ViewBag.EmailAddresses as SelectList, 
    null,
    htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" }
)
```

However, it only works when I have it setup like this:

Controller (works):

```
ViewBag.FromRecipientID = new[]
    {
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Select an Email Address", Value = "" } 
    }
    .Concat(
        new SelectList( db.EmailAddresses, "Oid", "Name", null )
    );
```

Razor view (works):

```
@Html.DropDownList(
    "FromRecipientID", 
    //Binding SelectList isn't required, assumption of ViewBag Name and Property
    null, 
    htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" }
)
```

Is there an alternative?  I'm not sure what I am missing.

## Edit #1:

I've been able to update my ViewModel, on Edit, populate `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> EmailAddresses` along with the EmailAddressID:

```
public ActionResult Edit(Guid? id)
{
    //...
    //Omitted information   

    //List of EmailMessages
    formView.EmailMessages = form.EmailMessages
        .Select(f =>
        {
            //Populate IEnumerable<SelectListItem>
            f.EmailAddresses = new SelectList(db.EmailAddresses, "Oid", "Name", f.FromRecipientID);
            return f;
        })
    ;

    //More omitted information
    //...

}
```

IEnumerable contained the following:

```
My Email    > id = 1
Your Email  > id = 2 (this should be the selected item)

//Note that the DropDownListFor examples below added "Select an Email Address" to the top of the list
```

The below Razor cshtml code was an attempt to show what I have tried and the result, I only had one `DropDownListFor` active at a time (I noticed that the first instance was the only one that "could" work properly).

In my `PartialView`, I have the `FromRecipientID` (Guid) or `FromRecipient` (EmailAddress object):

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FromRecipientID, "FromRecipientID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">

        @* Works, selected ID 2 (because of Model.EmailAddesses) *@
        @* On Save error though, noted below *@
        @Html.DropDownListFor(
            model => model.FromRecipient, 
            Model.EmailAddresses, 
            "Select an Email Address", 
            htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })

        @* Failed, no ViewBag.FromRecipient (makes sense) *@
        @Html.DropDownListFor(
            model => model.FromRecipient, 
            null, 
            "Select an Email Address", 
            htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })

        @* Does not work, selected "Select an Email Address" *@
        @Html.DropDownListFor(
            model => model.FromRecipientID, 
            Model.EmailAddresses, 
            "Select an Email Address", 
            htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })

        @* Works, selected ID 2 (but because of ViewBag.FromRecipientID) *@
        @Html.DropDownListFor(
            model => model.FromRecipientID, 
            null, 
            "Select an Email Address", 
            htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })

        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FromRecipientID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

For the first example, the one that populated properly (`... model => model.FromRecipient, Model.EmailAddresses, "Select an Email Address" ...`) didn't work on Save, I receive the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 
'There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'FromRecipient'.'
```

This seems to be coming from the ModelState being invalid, I get the following:

```
{"The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'ContentPub.Models.Mail.EmailAddress' failed because no type converter can convert between these types."}
```

I get it, I have a value of "2" but the DropDownListFor is trying to set model => model.FromRecipient.

Am I over-thinking this?

## Edit #2

Wow, hate to report this as it was a simple fix/issue, but I need to...

I removed the old ViewBag setup that I had:

```
//ViewBag.FromRecipientID = new[] { new SelectListItem { Text = "Select an Email Address", Value = "" } }
//    .Concat(new SelectList(db.EmailAddresses, "Oid", "Name", null));
```

As I see it now, this was getting in the way of my testing.

This is the `DropDownListFor` that is working properly:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(
    model => model.FromRecipientID, 

    //When the ViewBag.FromRecipientID was active, Model.EmailAddesses wasn't being used
    // and was causing some type of conflict
    Model.EmailAddresses, 

    "Select an Email Address", 
    htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

I will do more testing (and answer my own question when confirmed), but I think this is what I needed all along.

Comment: `ViewBag.EmailAddresses as SelectList` is incorrect because you're actually creating an unknown subclass of `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` from Linq's `.Concat` method - it accepts your concrete `new SelectList` as an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` - check the overload info in your IDE or the selected overload in the compiled CIL if you don't believe me. The `EmailAddresses` property does not contain an actual `SelectList` instance. I also recommend avoiding the use of `ViewBag` entirely and have strongly-typed `ViewModel` members instead.

Comment: Also, is there a reason you're using `DropDownList` instead of `DropDownListFor`?

Comment: I like the idea of a strongly types ViewModel, I may run into an issue as this area is a `PartialView`. The Scaffolding setup `DropDownList` automatically, I'll check out `DropDownListFor` in greater detail. Thank you.

Comment: `Model.EmailAddresses` which `EmailAddresses` declared as `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` is preferred over `ViewBag` usage. Also you need additional `string` property to hold selected item value if you're using `DropDownListFor`.

Comment: It doesn't. And it should not be (refer [Can the ViewBag name be the same as the Model property name in a DropDownList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37161202/can-the-viewbag-name-be-the-same-as-the-model-property-name-in-a-dropdownlist/37162557#37162557))

Comment: Updated my question with my new findings/issues, @tetsuya-yamamoto can you provide an example for "you need additional `string` property to hold selected item value if you're using `DropDownListFor`", that may be the issue I have experiencing.

Comment: I had a midnight though about the old ViewBag item of `FormRecipientID` that didn't need to be there.  Edited Question, proper answer will follow once I get the code working properly.