# Show Select from foreign model in view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I am VERY new to MVC.

I am using .NET core 2.0 with EntityFrameworkCore. I have my contexts established and data, models, controllers, views all working at the most basic level.

I have model/view/controller for `HRIS` data and model/view/controller for `Entity` (not Entity Framework) data (among others).

`Entity` model contains `company`, `division`, `location`, `contract`, etc.

On the `HRIS` view `Index.cshtml` page I need to pull all entities that are of type `contract` and populate a `<select>` which will then determine which `contract` the HRIS data is related to. Example: User sees contract select and picks Contract1. All future actions in this view will reference HRIS data associated with Contract1.

Basic flow scheme:

1. User enters New Contract in `Entity` View.
2. User goes to `HRIS` view and selects Contract from Select.
3. User imports `HRIS` data from text file that will be associated with
   that Contract.
4. User proceeds to view/model/controller to edit imported `HRIS` data.

I realize that my code must handle the actual import and associating the data with the contract. I'm just trying to find out how to populate the `<select>` within the confines of MVC while the `Contract` data is in the `Entity` model and not in the `HRIS` model.

I've allowed the framework to create `<select>` controls for other items in the application using:

```
<select asp-for="EntityTypeID" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.EntityTypeID"></select>
```

and

```
ViewData["EntityTypeID"] = new SelectList(_context.EntityTypes, "EntityTypeID", "EntityTypeName");
```

and this works very well but these are within the same model.

Important note: after data is imported, it will be handled completely by another view/model/controller if that makes any difference in how this is handled.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Your actually using asp.net-core-mvc

Comment: Its not really clear what you struggling with. And it would help if you showed your models and the controller method view where your wanting to create the `<select>`

Comment: And as a side note,do not use the same name for the property your binding to and the `SelectList` (refer [Can the ViewBag name be the same as the Model property name in a DropDownList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37161202/can-the-viewbag-name-be-the-same-as-the-model-property-name-in-a-dropdownlist/37162557#37162557)). And do not use data models in your view - use a view model - refer [What is ViewModel in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)

Comment: And for a typical example of how generating a `<select>` with a view model, refer [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366305/the-viewdata-item-that-has-the-key-xxx-is-of-type-system-int32-but-must-be-o)