# How to get the value of @DropDownListFor in [HttpPost] at controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am not able to get the value of  @Html.DropDownListFor to a controller.
I am new to MVC.
Here I am adding the code.

**Model**

```
 public IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem> CatID { get; set; }
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Motors()
{
 ViewBag.CatID = new SelectList(db1.motors.ToList(), "id", "cat");
 return View();
}
```

**View**

//(in view **DATA** is properly loading from database)

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CatID, ViewBag.CatID as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

**Controller**(*Back to controller after post*)

```
[HttpPost]

    public ActionResult Motors(MotorInput collection)

         {
            MotorInput obj = new MotorInput
               {
               CatID = collection.CatID
               }; 
              return View(collection);
         }
```

I am just looking for a way to get the value of @Html.DropDownListFor selected from view to the controller.

[Screenshot of Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4KLZ.png)

[Screenshot of Controller after post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCNrT.png)

Comment: I'm assuming that the `CatID` property is in `MotorInput` class, am I right?

Comment: You cannot bind a `<select>` to a collection of complex objects (which is what `CatId` is). You need  a property say `int SelectedCategory` to bind to.

Comment: Have a look at my post

Comment: @Stephen Muecke so what changes I should do in my Model and controller. Finding this little difficult to understand.

Comment: Have a look at the code in [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366305/the-viewdata-item-that-has-the-key-xxx-is-of-type-system-int32-but-must-be-o). And your editing data so always use a view model - [What is ViewModel in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)

Comment: ViewModel was MotorInput. I managed to solve the issue, Stephen. Just by changing in Model class ( public int CatID { get; set; } ). I have posted my solution down. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the Solution for above issue.

**Model**(MotorInput.cs)

```
public int CatID { get; set; }
```

**Controller**(UserController.cs) //To load in View page setting to viewBag from database

```
public ActionResult Motors()
        {
            this.ViewBag.CatID = new SelectList(this.db1.motors, "id", "cat");
            return View();
        }
```

**View**(Motors.cshtml)

```
@model BLL.Models.MotorInput
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Motors";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_UserLayout.cshtml";
}

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
         @Html.DropDownList("CatID", (SelectList)ViewData["CatID"], "-- Select Category --", new { @class = "form-control" })


     <input type="submit" value="Create">
    }
```

**Controller**(Usercontroller.cs) // After post.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Motors(MotorInput collection)// MotorInput is the class where CatId is set as int.(Model class)
           {
             MotorInput obj = new MotorInput
                       {
                           CatID = collection.CatID,
                       };
                    return View(collection);
          }
```

This helps to get the dropdown value to controller from view.

Comment: You cannot have the same name for the property your binding to and the `SelectList` - refer [Can the ViewBag name be the same as the Model property name in a DropDownList?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37161202/will-there-be-any-conflict-if-i-specify-the-viewbag-name-to-be-equal-to-the-mode/37162557#37162557)