# Set current AspNetUser as default UserId on one a table when a new object is created

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework and MVC with Individual User Accounts and I have a table called "Kit" that has a UserId column which is linked to the AspNetUser 'ID' as the foreign key.

When I go to create a new kit and save to the database I want the 'UserId' of my Kit table to be the current ASPNetUser that is logged in.

But currently when I create the new Kit object it just sets the UserId to NULL and never picks up the current user logged in.

What am I missing here?

**Controller Create()**

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "KitId,KitName,ProductId,UserId")] Kit kit)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Kits.Add(kit);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    ViewBag.ProductId = new SelectList(db.Products, "ProductId", "ProductName", kit.ProductId);
    ViewBag.UserId = new SelectList(db.AspNetUsers, "Id", "Email", kit.UserId);
    return View(kit);
}
```

**View**

```cs
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AspNetUser.Id, "User", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2"})
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserId, "Email", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled" } })
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the row in my database and you can see UserId was never populated

```cs
KitId   KitName ProductId   Available   LoanId  UserId
 3      TestKit    12         NULL       NULL    NULL
```

Comment: Ok, so no way to have it displayed in an @Html.EditFor that the user can't edit? That's the only reason I disabled the field.  Thank you by the way, that's helpful.

Comment: Makes sense.  But this is good to know for other views.  How would I set it before saving to the database.  I have "kit.UserId =" right before db.SaveChanges(); but I am not sure what value I am setting to UserId.  I thought it would be AspNetUser.Id but I get "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'AspNetUser.Id'"

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabled controls do not submit a value, so the value of `UserId` in the POST method will be `null` (the default for the property - although its unclear why you have made it nullable). While you could make the input readonly (using `new { @readonly = "readonly" }`), the correct approach is to set the value of the property in the POST method immediately before saving the record to prevent malicious users posting back invalid data and discovering the ID's of other users.

```cs
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    kit.UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId(); // assumes your using Identity
    db.Kits.Add(kit);
    ...
```

At the very least, your `[Bind]` attribute should exclude `KitId` and `UserId` properties, however the preferred method, especially when editing data, is to use a view model containing only those properties you need in the view, and that view model will also include `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` properties from you dropdownlists rather than using `ViewBag`. Refer [What is ViewModel in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc).

As a side note, your naming your `SelectList` the same as the property your binding to which will not work correctly (refer [Can the ViewBag name be the same as the Model property name in a DropDownList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37161202/can-the-viewbag-name-be-the-same-as-the-model-property-name-in-a-dropdownlist) for a detailed explanation), and there is no point setting the `Selected` property using the 4th parameter of the `SelectList` constructor (its ignored when binding to a model property)