# How to create Razor dropdown from table records

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, dbcontext

I have a table called `Riders`, containing information about horse riders. I want to use `FirstName` and 'ID' columns to populate a select dropdown. I've been bashing my head with this for a good 3 hours now and I get the same result - A dropdown list with same amount of options as my table recors, with text: `System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem`. I pass the values to the View like this:

```
 ViewBag.Riders = new SelectList(
    db.Riders
        .Select(r => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = "test",
                Text = "test"
            })
        .ToArray());
```

If I hover over `ViewBag.Raiders` while debugging I can see some system fields and then `items`, which contains my `SelectList` (full of "test") and `Results View`, which contains `SelectList` with Text values of `System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem`. What is the problem here? Where did that `Results View` come from and why is it populated with `SelectItem` class name?

My Razor looks like this:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Riders", ViewBag.Raiders as SelectList)
```

I have tried using couple of different overloads of this `DropDownList` but to no success.

What am I doing wrong here? I thought accessing database with MVC is supposed to be easy. Its not intuitive for sure.

Comment: Using `new SelectList()` to create another identical `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` is pointless. `ViewBag.Riders = db.Riders.Select(x => new SelectListItem{ Value = x.ID.ToString(), Text = x.FirstName });`

Comment: And you cannot use the same name for the property and the SelectList - refer [Can the ViewBag name be the same as the Model property name in a DropDownList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37161202/can-the-viewbag-name-be-the-same-as-the-model-property-name-in-a-dropdownlist)

Comment: Or if you want to use `SelectList`, then its `ViewBag.Riders = new SelectList(db.Riders, "ID", "FirstName");` - note the 2nd parameter refer to the name of the property to use for the `value` attribute and the 3rd parameter refers to the named of the property to use for the option text

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks, it works now. However I had do use `db.Riders.AsEnumerable().Select`, otherwise it would throw error

Comment: Then you also have another problem with your code (something you did not show) because its not necessary

Comment: @StephenMuecke What Can i do wrong there? The Table definition looks like this: `public DbSet<Rider> Riders { get; set; }`.

Comment: I can only assume you must be wrapping your code in a `using` statement so its disposed before the model is returned to the view

Comment: @StephenMuecke No such thing. I do not recollect the exact error but it was something like `LINQ to Entity. Cannot resolve Select`. I read about it in the internet and a proposed solution was to add `AsEnumerable` before `Select` query.