# html.hiddenfor for disabled dropdownlist with default value MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have edited de Create view to add a hidden field control, but i cant get the value

```
<div class="form-group">
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmpresaId, "Empresa", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("EmpresaId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled" })
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.EmpresaId)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmpresaId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
</div>
```

html created is:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="EmpresaId">Empresa</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <select class="form-control" disabled="disabled" id="EmpresaId" name="EmpresaId">
              <option selected="selected" value="1">Farmacia MZ</option>
              <option value="2">Credesa</option>
            </select>
            <input length="19" id="EmpresaId" name="EmpresaId" type="hidden" value="">
            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="EmpresaId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

As you can see hidden input has no value.

On Controller is DropDownList default value set:

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ApplicationUser usr = db.Users.Find(User.Identity.GetUserId().ToString());
        int userId = (int)usr.EmpresaId;
        ViewBag.CategoriaId = new SelectList(db.Categorias, "CategoriaId", "Nombre");
        ViewBag.EmpresaId = new SelectList(db.Empresas, "EmpresaId", "Nombre", userId); <-- defalut value for disabled DropDownList
        ViewBag.MarcaId = new SelectList(db.Marcas, "MarcaId", "Nombre");
        return View();
    }
```

I've searched quite a lot but i dont understand what is the mistake. Help is wellcome !

Comment: Where are you not able to get it ?

Comment: on rendered html i see that value for hidden input is not set, besides EmpresaId is not saved on model

Comment: Because in your GET action you are setting it to view bag. You need to set it to your view model property.

Comment: i can set the value for hidden input from selected value on dropdownlist?

Answer (score 0):

This `HiddenFor` helper clearly bounds to `EmpresaId` viewmodel property:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.EmpresaId)
```

The hidden field value has blank value because it not assigned from corresponding viewmodel property inside GET action method, since you're actually assigned default value of `EmpresaId` to `ViewBag.EmpresaId` which contains `SelectList`.

```
ViewBag.EmpresaId = new SelectList(db.Empresas, "EmpresaId", "Nombre", userId);
```

Hence you need to create a viewmodel instance, then assign default values to viewmodel properties and return to view in GET action method:

```
// create new instance of viewmodel and set default property value
var model = new ViewModel();
model.EmpresaId = userId;

// return default values from viewmodel to view page
return View(model);
```

Or simply set default value during viewmodel instance creation:

```
var model = new ViewModel()
{
    EmpresaId = userId;
};

return View(model);
```

As a side note, always use strongly-typed `DropDownListFor` helper instead of `DropDownList` to bind with viewmodel properties:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.EmpresaId, ViewBag.EmpresaList as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled" })
```

Comment: Suggest you read [Can the ViewBag name be the same as the Model property name in a DropDownList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37161202/can-the-viewbag-name-be-the-same-as-the-model-property-name-in-a-dropdownlist) to understand why the last code snippet will not work

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Stephen. I realized OP wrongly use a model property name as `SelectList` property in `ViewBag` and it's responsibility of OP to change it into other name.