# Dropdownlist not displaying value on Edit page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dropdownlistfor

Im populating a dropdownlist from a table, and the problem is when I go to the Edit page, it didnt select the value but instead show "Select Company".
 Im using AspNetUsers default table, and add another column on it called Company (Integer).[image]
I have another model & Table called TBL_COMP which map to AspNetUsers.

```
 public class TBL_COMP
{
    [Key]
    public int CompId { get; set; }
    public string CompDesc { get; set; }
}
```

In my models (UserViewModels) I have this

```
    public int Company { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Company")]
    public TBL_COMP TBL_COMP { get; set; }
```

This is the dropdownlist in view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Company, new SelectList(ViewBag.Company, "Value", "Text"), "Select Company", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

and this is the controller:

```
ViewBag.Company = new SelectList(db.TBL_COMP.ToList(), "CompId", "CompDesc", user.Company);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can the ViewBag name be the same as the Model property name in a DropDownList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37161202/can-the-viewbag-name-be-the-same-as-the-model-property-name-in-a-dropdownlist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ViewBag.Company` is already contained `SelectList`, just cast it on the view (creating another `SelectList` from existing `SelectList` is pointless):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Company, ViewBag.Company as SelectList, "Select Company", 
                      new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Or use strongly-typed `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` instead:

**Viewmodel**

```
public class UserViewModels
{
    // other properties

    public List<SelectListItem> Companies { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller action**

```
var model = new UserViewModels();

model.Companies = db.TBL_COMP.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.CompDesc, Value = x.CompId }).ToList();
```

**View**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Company, Model.Companies, "Select Company", new { @class = "form-control" })
```